# Can't locate audio recordings which I recorded with a voice record app on my Lumia 920

Tags: storage, audio-recording

I can't locate audio recordings which I recorded with a voice record app on my Lumia 920. Anytime I record, the message "the file has been saved to phone" appears but I can't see it in my managed files.